Spring Cloud RabbitMQ Functional Routing expression not working
I am migrating an old Spring Boot 2.3.3 application with to Spring Boot 3.3
The application is using Spring Cloud and RabbitMQ.
Old: Spring Boot 2.3.3 with Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR8
New: Spring Boot 3.3.1 with Spring Cloud 2023.0.2
I have changed the Spring configuration and code to use the new Spring Cloud Functional programming model for Rabbit Queues.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/spring-cloud-function/programming-model.html
I have done this migration before on other application, but this time I am faced with a routing problem I cannot find a solution how to resolve.
I have two incoming queues with same destination name, but with a routing key header to determine which function to route the message to.
However I cannot get this routing to work after migration. The unit tests which worked fine before migration now fails.
That is because a single message either DeliveryMessage or CargoMessage it routed to both functions (processDelivery;processCargo).
Maybe the two Queues should have had different destination names, but I cannot do anything about that, since I cannot change the application (storage-service) sending these messages.
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: processBaseDelivery;processDelivery;processCargo
      #routing-expression: "headers.amqp_receivedRoutingKey.toString().contains('delivery') ? 'processDelivery' : 'processCargo'"
      routing-expression: "headers['amqp_receivedRoutingKey'] == 'delivery.INSERT' ? 'processDelivery' : 'processCargo'"
    stream:
      bindings:
        processBaseDelivery-in-0:
          destination: transport.baseDeliveryResponse
          group: delivery-service
        processDelivery-in-0:
          destination: storage
          group: delivery-service.delivery
        processCargo-in-0:
          destination: storage
          group: delivery-service.cargo
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          processBaseDelivery-in-0:
            consumer:
              transacted: true
              requeue-rejected: true
              bindingRoutingKey: delivery.response
          processDelivery-in-0:
            consumer:
              max-concurrency: 1
              autoBindDlq: true
              transacted: true
              requeue-rejected: false
              bindingRoutingKey: delivery.*
          processCargo-in-0:
            consumer:
              max-concurrency: 1
              autoBindDlq: true
              transacted: true
              requeue-rejected: false
              bindingRoutingKey: cargo.*

My Unit Test for processDelivery with delivery.INSERT as routing key.
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
public class MessageProcessorServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private CargoService cargoService;

    @MockBean
    private DeliveryService deliveryService;

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination inputDestination;

    @Test
    public void processDelivery_delete() {
        final DeliveryMessage deliveryMessage = new DeliveryMessage();
        deliveryMessage.setId(1L);
        deliveryMessage.setOperation(Operation.DELETE);

        inputDestination.send(
            MessageBuilder.withPayload(deliveryMessage)
                .setHeader(AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY, "delivery.INSERT")
                .build(), "lagerlegging");

        Mockito.verify(deliveryService, new Times(1))
            .deleteDelivery(eq(1L));
        Mockito.verifyNoInteractions(cargoService);
    }

}

I have tried using Consumer with and without Message for both functions:
public Consumer<DeliveryMessage> processDelivery()
public Consumer<Message<DeliveryMessage>> processDelivery()


According to the Spring Cloud Function documentation, the routing-expression has an effect only if we call special functionRouter function: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/spring-cloud-function/programming-model.html#messageroutingcallback

Spring Cloud Function provides routing feature allowing you to invoke a single function which acts as a router to an actual function you wish to invoke.


The RoutingFunction is registered in FunctionCatalog under the name functionRouter.

However you do this bindings:
    processDelivery-in-0:
      destination: storage
      group: delivery-service.delivery
    processCargo-in-0:
      destination: storage
      group: delivery-service.cargo

So, you do not use a function router and looks like you indeed bind both your functions to the same RabbitMQ exchange. Then their is a RabbitMQ binding to that exchange with queues like storage.delivery-service.delivery and storage.delivery-service.cargo for those functions, respectively.
You probably just can leverage this RabbitMQ binding feature for the desired routing. See binding-routing-key property: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/rabbit/rabbit_overview/rabbitmq-consumer-properties.html.
You will need to use a routing-key-expression property on the producer side then to initiate that RabbitMQ routing mechanics: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/rabbit/rabbit_overview/prod-props.html
But in the end you see that routing-expression for Spring Cloud Function is wrong direction for your solution.
UPDATE
This is a simple Spring Cloud Stream application with RabbitMQ binder proving that routing-key-expression does the trick to router messages properly on the RabbitMQ side:
@SpringBootApplication
public class So78815061Application {

    public final Sinks.Many<Message<String>> producerSink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

    public final CountDownLatch deliveryReceived = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public final CountDownLatch noCargoInDelivery = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public final CountDownLatch cargoReceived = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public final CountDownLatch noDeliveryInCargo = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So78815061Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<String> processDelivery() {
        return data -> {
            System.out.println("processDelivery: " + data);
            if (data.startsWith("delivery")) {
                deliveryReceived.countDown();
            }
            if (data.startsWith("cargo")) {
                noCargoInDelivery.countDown();
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<String> processCargo() {
        return data -> {
            System.out.println("processCargo: " + data);
            if (data.startsWith("cargo")) {
                cargoReceived.countDown();
            }
            if (data.startsWith("delivery")) {
                noDeliveryInCargo.countDown();
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> producer() {
        return this.producerSink::asFlux;
    }

}

The application.properties:
spring.application.name=so-78815061
spring.cloud.function.definition=processDelivery;processCargo;producer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processDelivery-in-0.destination=storage
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processDelivery-in-0.group=delivery-service.delivery
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.processDelivery-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=delivery.*
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processCargo-in-0.destination=storage
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processCargo-in-0.group=delivery-service.cargo
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.processCargo-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=cargo.*
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.producer-out-0.destination=storage
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.producer-out-0.producer.routing-key-expression=headers.my_routing_key

And unit test:
@SpringBootTest
class So78815061ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    So78815061Application application;

    @Test
    void rabbitMqRoutesMessageProperly() throws InterruptedException {
        this.application.producerSink.tryEmitNext(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload("deliveryMessage")
                        .setHeader("my_routing_key", "delivery.INSERT")
                        .build());

        this.application.producerSink.tryEmitNext(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload("cargoMessage")
                        .setHeader("my_routing_key", "cargo.UPDATE")
                        .build());

        assertThat(this.application.deliveryReceived.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
        assertThat(this.application.cargoReceived.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();

        assertThat(this.application.noCargoInDelivery.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isFalse();
        assertThat(this.application.noDeliveryInCargo.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isFalse();
    }

}

I think the TestChannelBinderConfiguration does not have an ability to do such a routing since all of those spring.cloud.stream.rabbit. properties are just ignored.

Then routing-expression is not what I need. The old code is using @StreamListener and works to call either delivery message (deliveryIn) or cargo message (cargoIn). Can I get this to work with the new Functional model or do I still need to use the @StreamListener?
Both the MQs has consumer configuration with bindingRoutingKey.

Yeah.. I see now: bindingRoutingKey: delivery.*. Do you have a proper routing-key-expression on the producer side?

The producer does supply a routingKey. Although the producer is in a different application. This is working fine today when both Consumer app and Producer app is running with the older Spring 2 and Spring Cloud v3.
But this is my Unit Test not working. When I simulate sending a message on the MQ, then both Consumer functions is called.

I think the problem is with @Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class). This one does not have knowledge about RabbitMQ binding feature. Therefore nothing is going to be routed properly from there.

See an UPDATE in my answer. You cannot do such a routing using TestChannelBinderConfiguration

Does that mean I cannot test this routed receiving MQ?

As showed you in my answer you can test it, but you have to do that against RabbitMQ Binder. That AMQP routing feature is really native to the AMQP broker. When you use TestChannelBinderConfiguration, then native broker backs off and, therefore, all of its native feature are out of the picture.
